# How to fetch user ID in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Google script linked to a spreadsheet containing multiple email ids and some data related to them. The script will send an email containing an HTML button to every id in the spreadsheet. What I am doing is that when the user clicks that button in its mail, it will fetch the data from the spreadsheet respective to that email id. 
What I am unable to do is how to fetch user id of that particular user when that user clicks the button (that script sent in the mail) and send it with the POST response, so that script can know which user is asking for information and fetch data from spreadsheet only for that particular user.

Comment: Take a look at the [User documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user). It's not a user id but an e-mail address that you could use.

Comment: Give every button a unique parameter to add in the POST body. In your webapp handler, use that unique info to choose the right row. This is the same idea as advertisers knowing who clicked the links in the email they sent.

Comment: @Casper it will only give the email address of the user who is running the script not who is clicking the button and asking for information.

Comment: @tehhowch, I tried something like this. I created a hidden field in the HTML form containing a unique id for every user, who is going to receive the mail with form. After clicking the button, this ID is attached with POST response and script can compare it from the spreadsheet, but the problem with this is if someone changes the ID value of that hidden element from browser developer window, that user can get data of another person.

Comment: @tehhowch,  Example if the script is sending mail to two users ABC and DEF with their unique ID 1 and 2 as hidden HTML element. Normally when ABC clicks the button in the mail, ID 1 will go in POST response but ABC can go to inspect element in chrome and change the value of that HTML element to 2 and script will think response came from DEF.

Comment: @hemantA there are much better unique items than guessable consecutive integers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Casper's suggestion and used the email address of the active user and then split it to get the id part which then I can verify.